# The first column remains unsorted after sort the grid view in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I want to sort the columns of datagridview in vb.net windows application, but when sorting columns, the first column should remain fixed as this is the 'serial number' column.
How to achieve this?

Please help

Comment: If that's the identifier, why should it remain fixed? It belongs to every record. For example, consider a `Country`-table with ID and Name, if the ID-column stays fixed and the user sorts by name, the wrong ID's will be shown next to the country-name after sorting.

Comment: Agree with Tim.. I mostly hide the ID field as it make no sense to users. If you want a count I achieve this by doing a datagridview count and have that as as a value in a lable or panel title.

Comment: You want to sort the rows, not the columns.  What exactly does the other data represent that you think that "sorting" it means associating it with different serial numbers?

Comment: Each record in the datagridview has an Id column. There are other columns which will be sorted. At this point, the id column is also getting jumbled.I don't want that to happen..the id column should remain in order. Is there any event in datagridview by which this is possible?